# Echo the line number of the code in a log file

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

In my script I am using echo and directing the text to a log file like below

```
echo "`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"` The script is running.. " >> $log_File
```

How do I print the line number of the echo into the logfile ?

currently in the log file :

```
01032012141215 The script is running..
```

into the log file i want this to come as:

```
01032012141215 100 The script is running..
```

where 100 is the line number of the echo in the script

Comment: Why are you using such convoluted quotes?.  You could do: 'echo "$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S ) The script is running.. "' or just 'echo $(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S ) The script is running ..' or skip the backticks entirely and do: date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S | tr -d '\012'; echo The script is running..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find the line number of the current command in the variable $LINENO

```
echo "`date +"%d%m%Y%H%M%S"` $LINENO The script is running.. " >> $log_File
```

I'm not sure that this is a POSIX requirement, but at least most modern shells should provide this variable (`bash` sure does)